# Can I dynamically change input to dropdown menu that queries from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is my code, it appends the input form after the user clicks the "Add more" button.

How can I change the input field to a dropdown menu that queries the data from mysql?

Thank you ^^

### My HTML code

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My javascript

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        var i=1;  
        $('#add').click(function(){  
            i++;  
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
        }); 

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
        });  

        $('#submit').click(function(){            
            $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                    alert(data);  
                    $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
            });  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you can. If you add an **id** to the *td* of the input, then use jQuery's _html()_ function to put whatever you want in that table cell.

Comment: Doesn't need an id, he can use other methods to select that td